# Display service variable in component

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is an Angular 6, Firestore, and Firebase project. I want to display different user information pending who is logged in. I'm using *Firebase* for authentication and *Firestore* to hold additional data about my users, such as their `displayName`s. My databases look something like this.

**Authentication (Firebase)**

1. email = one@gmail.com
   userId = 101
2. email = two@gmail.com
   userId = 202

**Firestore Users Collection**

1. email = one@gmail.com
   userId = 101
   displayName = oneDisplayName
2. email = two@gmail.com
   userId = 202
   displayName = twoDisplayName

I have a `user.service.ts` that manages both of these in my app. Using this service, what I want to do is (a) when someone is logged in, pull their `displayName` from the `Firestore Users Collection` (b) set `displayName` equal to a variable in my service (c) inject my service into any component and show `displayName` in the `component.html`. I am able to grab `displayName` in the service, but can't successfully transfer it to a component.

Here is the code. What is the better way to do this?

**user.service.ts**

```
## imports and @injectable are up here ## 

export class UserService {
  usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
  users: Observable<User[]>;
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  username: string;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private router: Router,
              private afs: AngularFirestore) {
      this.usersCollection = this.afs.collection('users');
      this.users = this.usersCollection.valueChanges();
      this.user = afAuth.authState;

      this.user.subscribe(user => {
          if (user === null) {
            this.loggedIn = false;
          } else {
            this.loggedIn = true;
            this.usersCollection.doc(`${user.uid}`).ref.get()
              .then((doc) => {
                this.username = doc.data().displayName; <-- WORKS IN SERVICE BUT NOT COMPONENT ####
              });
          }
      });
   }
```

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import { UserService } from '../user.service';

export class NavbarComponent {
  username;

  @Component({
    providers: [ UserService ]
  })

  constructor(private userserv: UserService) {
    this.username = this.userserv.username; <-- UNDEFINED
  }
}
```

**navbar.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar">
  {{ username }}
<nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To always retrieve the up-to-date value from the service, define the property as a getter in the component class:

```
public get displayName(): string {
  return this.userserv.username;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. The `public get displayName() ... ` method is placed within the `navbar.component.ts` constructor like this:  `export class NavbarComponent { public get displayName() ... }`.